# Can the Jobs/Careers team explain to employers the purpose of the "Remote" option a bit better?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Based on the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269210/186281) posted last November, jobs with the "Remote" option shouldn't be "from time to time". Recently, I've been going through remote postings and see several that are *at least* unclear if they are hiring for both remote and in office employees. At worst, they are offering "work from home days", not a full time remote work option.

A few examples, though my goal isn't to shame the postings. It's to show that it's fairly common.

- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104813/full-stack-javascript-developer-motion-ai

  > What you'll get:
  >   Flexible PTO, **work from home days**, health insurance, generous equity options, competitive salary, onsite fitness, cafeteria and more.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > For those outside of the Chicago area, initial remote work is acceptable - but we are working to assemble a team within the greater Chicago region, so willingness to relocate is a must.
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/83126/front-end-developer-social-networking-and-big-rfactr-providing-the

  > Expand your network: We have a great location and work environment at the Packard Place, the premier technology incubator located in Uptown Charlotte, NC
  >
  > ...
  >
  > We have great benefits
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Work at Packard Place, Premiere Tech Incubator in Charlotte
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/106492/director-of-engineering-or-lead-software-developer-voteorg

  > Is comfortable working remotely if needed
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/106472/senior-developer-hacker-java-developer-the-washington-post

  > Flex time and ability to work from home
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104648/technical-engagement-lead-boldradius-solutions?

  > Location: Preference to candidates from Ottawa-Gatineau (Canada), San Francisco (California, US), New York City (US), Toronto (Canada), Montreal (Canada) and Saskatoon (Canada). Remote options within North America will be considered.
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104632/senior-generalist-engineer-moneythink

  > You’ll be given enough space to work (we’re located in a hard-working but fun co-working space), with access to whiteboards, phone booths, and meeting rooms, but we are also flexible on partial remote work.

There are more, but these are just in the past few days and ones that caught my eye initially.

Can the Careers team clarify, for employers, what the "Remote" option means? This may need to be a change on the UI that the person inputting the job posting sees, it may be training, it may be something else. I can certainly flag these posts, but the mistake seem common enough that a small reeducation may be needed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks for pointing these out! Consider these flagged. We'll reach out to the reps and the companies, and work with them to clarify policy and rework the listings.

We're pretty clear on the job post form:

[image]

but will definitively give this some more thought and see if there isn't anything else we can do.

Comment: As a job candidate, it'd be nice if I could select "full remote" to avoid partial remote on Fridays job listings, select "city wide remote" or "country wide remote" or "continent wide remote", select my citizenship "french" to avoid US only candidates job listings. All of these criteria would have been set by the user creating the job listing.

Comment: @Stephane especially the regional restrictions would be something worth adding, maybe even as option for the companies. I had one recommendation for weeks which had "[only US!]" in the title...

Comment: Unfortunately, I am writing this in September 2019 and it still has the same problem. I can't find remote jobs for non-US citizens.