# Stack Overflow Jobs - Remote but "Country X only please"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

*This question/request is very similar to another question I found, but the key aspect differs. As such, this is not a duplicate of [Can the Jobs/Careers team explain to employers the purpose of the "Remote" option a bit better?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316527/can-the-jobs-careers-team-explain-to-employers-the-purpose-of-the-remote-optio).*

When looking for remote jobs, I want them to be truly remote. Recently, I've been finding job listings containing the remote option with a "US only" policy in the job description. This is annoying.

A recent example would be this listing, by iFit: [Senior Javascript Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/35786/senior-javascript-developer-ifit). If I filter on permanent, remote jobs with JavaScript and Node.js as tags, this is a featured result. Being from the Netherlands however, this listing has no value to me.

Please allow the companies to set specific countries or regions when they create their job listings, so that I will not be bothered with listings that do match all my specifications, but are still useless to me because of a restriction in location.

Comment: This is something that has annoyed me for a long time and to be honest it still isn't clear to the job *seekers* what "remote" is supposed to mean to the prospective employer - should we waste our time applying for this position? Just saying "remote" is *not* helpful.

Comment: I have never heard back from these so called Remote jobs at stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe it's due to competition but not sure.

Answer (score 54):

We already do allow employers to specify where their job listing should be shown. This one clearly should have selected United States, but for some reason picked Worldwide, which contradicts the listing itself. I'll get someone to look into it.

Comment: Super! It's nice to have people on issues (even as small as these) being picked up on so quickly.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter no problem. We just need to figure out what the employer was intending before we make any changes, because it's possible that the listing is trying to say that on-site is US-only, but remote is allowed from anywhere. It's rather ambiguous as it stands currently.

Comment: It could also be that only U.S citizens are allowed, but from anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work from the candidate's side, though.  I can no longer seem to say "Show me jobs for X, flagged as remote and within X miles/km of [some location]"  This used to work previously and allows candidates within (say) the UK to look for remote jobs that are also within the UK.

Comment: Could SO check for the text typed in by the user posting the job listing, and warn on content such as: only, location, country, resident. To avoid the user restricting location in the text.

Comment: Still finding that this is an issue with a lot of remote listings.

Comment: Still finding many such jobs. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/207146/craftsmanship-focused-test-loving-full-stack-level-12?so=p&pg=1&offset=1&l=Remote&u=Km&d=20

Comment: Employees mark "Worldwide" audience because what they mean is "you can move to the US and here you can work in an office or remotely". 
What many devs needs is an option to filter out all geographically discriminating jobs.

Answer (score 39):

I guess "remote" is a blunt instrument. The range of options could include:

- we expect you to be in the same city, but can work from home most of the time
- we expect you to be in the same country, and to have the right to work there
- we expect you to be in or close to the same timezone, and to have the right to work in our country
- you can be anywhere, but must have the right to work in our country
- you can be anywhere, and we'll find a way to pay you legally.

Comment: Agreed - job posters should be forced to provider at least country/countries of residence / timezone as part of the listing if remote is selected.

Comment: Yes, more options can make the search easier.

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference between "from where" geographically and legally. Which one of these is addressed, or both? What if employer wishes to hire just Americans, but allows them to work from anywhere in the world? Or if employer is willful to hire foreigners, but only with relocation?

Answer (score 6):

some jobs in the US require the employee to be a US citizen and therefore, the "remote" resource must be in the US.

Comment: And since I'm not a citizen of the United States, I don't want to see this job listing. Simple as that.

Comment: There should be two criteria, one for the citizenship and one for the location.

Comment: But that should be mentioned too.

Answer (score 2):

I think companies should provide:

- Whether the job is 100% remote or not
- List of countries or regions where the candidate should be located. Could be something like: Europe, America, Asia, Germany, USA or Anywhere.
- Whether the candidate should be legally allowed to work out of a specific country (like having a visa or citizenship)

This would make way easier for companies to find the right people instead of having 100 applicants where only 5 meet the location/legal requirements. And also, it would help candidates to search for the jobs that they're actually able to apply to. It's a win win.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, this might solves many problems.