# Remote jobs without a location restriction (worldwide)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

The 'remote' option on the jobs website is often linked to being within the geographic boundary of a specific country (most often USA, Canada, and UK).

The feature request is to allow searching for remote jobs that do not have a geographic restriction (or at least filter out those that have a specific country restriction).

There is a related question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316789/stack-overflow-jobs-remote-but-country-x-only-please).

Comment: Are there really such jobs that hire irrespective of the residing country? I imagine there are visa restrictions everywhere?

Comment: Yes, there are such jobs, to give an example Wikimedia hires anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jobs feature was removed from StackOverflow in April 2022. Problem solved.