# Does "No office location" imply that the company will allow working from anywhere?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

Take [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/551620/r-d-software-engineer-general-dynamics-uk).

Does it mean they'll let one work from anywhere they want?

Or, looked at from the other side, what inputs do company provide when creating these job entries in order to show "No office location" and "Remote"?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently not. Always read the full description:

> ...this role could either be based working from home, with a requirement for travel to our sites or based within our offices in Chippenham or Oakdale depending upon your preference.

I've also seen companies that will only hire from within their county even though the role is completely remote, without an office location. (Not sure why exactly, maybe because it's easier when everyone's working under the same laws.) See also: [Stack Overflow Jobs - Remote but "Country X only please"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316789/6083675)

Comment: I expect it's just a hassle to pay wages out of the country. Unless you're paying a bill, but then it's not an employee, it's a contractor.

Comment: Different labor laws, different privacy laws, different regulations, different tax obligations, etc. There's a recent [letter to Ask A Manager](https://www.askamanager.org/2021/09/my-employee-relocated-and-didnt-tell-me.html) where a manager would have to pay $20K a year to incorporate in order to let their employees work outside of a headquarter city. There are companies that won't let you work remotely from Colorado because that state requires job postings to include salary info.

Comment: Laurel, even the part you quoted doesn't say anything about _where_ the home is allowed to be, though.