# Request (success) stories for Stack Overflow Jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I've googled and found few success stories about developers finding jobs on Stack Overflow. (I've mostly found people say they were unsuccessful e.g. [here](https://www.quora.com/Have-you-ever-found-a-job-or-contract-through-Stack-Overflow) and [here](https://www.quora.com/How-is-your-experience-with-using-Stack-Overflow-Jobs-to-find-jobs), so I'm eager to hear from folks who had success)

It would be great if Stack Overflow itself shared some of its users experience. What were their challenges, how soon did they land an interview, was it any different from other sites?

**EDIT:** This question is already answered, but if folks with 2-10k reps answer share their stories it would become more complete as job finding for users with 20k is easier. It usually means have been programming for at least 7-8 years and are more experienced than others.

Comment: So you're definitely not looking for the opposite of that at all, whatsoever, in any way, shape or form then?  Because I have a few of those experiences. :(

Comment: @Makoto to be honest, I **am**. Just wasn't sure if it's the right place to ask. If you think I can ask, then please edit the question and add an answer. I just want to gain more experience about posting jobs (successes or challenges)

Comment: No, I think this is okay...personally...I'd be curious to hear them too, frankly.

Comment: @Makoto sorry, "this" means what? The question as it is right now? or also asking the opposite?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear.  I think the question is fine.

Comment: I've applied for several different positions on SO Jobs, and asked a question to at least one employer. I've only gotten one reply, and that was to tell me that I didn't meet their standards because I don't have a CS degree. My eyes were sore from the rolling all that day. I keep hearing rumors about how your SO reputation can get you a job, but I just have not see any evidence of that.

Comment: Honestly, I've got some pretty bad (automatic) recommendations from Stack Overflow Jobs. Last one was a senior Drupal programmer ([maybe because of regex answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:7586+%5Bphp%5D)), for less money than I made 10 years ago at my first job. Then again, I wasn't actively looking for a job, so I can't comment on how well it actually works.

Comment: I've had a head hunter phone me and say they found my profile on SO. I was a unaware that people could see my phone number.

Comment: I was contacted few times over the time Jobs are online by head hunters and even by companies itself with more or less a match of my work field. But I do not actively search for a job And I am accustomed to job offers from other companies (even foreign). Even my present job was offered by company without any initiation from my side. My experience over the years is that multi company collaboration projects are the best motivation for companies to offer a job (once they noticed you're good). But my experience is biased by the fact that there is huge lack of people in my field of work.

Comment: I will leave this here... yeah here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias

Comment: Can this be a combination of success/fail stories? This seems like it could be great feedback to improve the system as a whole.

Comment: I was contacted by facebook. Wow. But I turned it down. For now

Comment: I actually landed my current role from a posting that was listed in the Jobs sidebar and it is far and away the best company I've ever worked for.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure what the 22 upvotes on your comment means...does it mean 22 people were disqualified because of not having a CS degeree?! or just that they didn't get a reply back from the employer...

Comment: The only experience I have with SO jobs is that every single job they shows me hard-requires a CS degree and they do not recognize a german dual apprenticeship. So in essence this service is largely pointless for me.

Comment: I've applied for 5 roles over a few months.  Two got me telephone interviews and the other three were completely silent after the "we got your application" automatic response.  I think no response at all is rude, if I come across anyone from those companies at industry events they are going to get a broadside

Comment: Also, reading this thread: it shows that Stackoverflow jobs is low quality.  There is no feedback path from potential employees to employers.  I was considering using  SO jobs for advertising our posts but won't be doing this now

Comment: Had the experience when I'd applied for a job and then it went to "this job no longer available"

Comment: @Phaeze and anyone else who HAS found a job with us - I am a marketing manager here at Stack Overflow and would love to learn more about your experiences.   Please email me at bturriff@stackoverflow.com.  I am hoping to use success stories to help people best use the service and also to improve how we present jobs to people who are interested.

Comment: @BryanTurriff I'm glad you're here, but seriously I wrote this question at Sep 5th and you replied back Oct 9th!? Maybe you replied back because there weren't enough responses idk, but such a slow response time makes doubt the commitment you're giving to jobs. I thought there would be some initiative or something much sooner...

Comment: @Honey - Hi - I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow so I'm really just starting to look at building some success stories in the last few weeks and I didn't see this post until the answer below came up with some really good feedback.  Thanks for posting this interesting question, I hope it surfaces a few more successful uses of the service.  Incidentally I have heard back from 2 people so far - so again thanks for your original post.

Comment: @BryanTurriff Cool, I actually asked this question because my contract could be ending soon and I just wanted to get a measure of Stackoverflow Jobs. I would like to post it here, because I don't like going through recruiters (who don't have proper technical knowledge) and each of them asking me the same question again and again or me having to give them my information again and again. I just want to tell them hey this is my resume, but also you can know a bit more about me through Stackoverflow and also them be able to pull my info instantly and submit for the HR who schedules interviews.

Comment: @BryanTurriff Where you able to write some stories somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: *I am writing this under an anonymous account to protect my identity for personal reasons. I am U.S. based and a 20k+ SO user. If someone from SO would like to contact me to verify, please feel free to do so.*

### Are we Spoon Fed?

One of the common themes I've seen on SO is the notion of being "spoon-fed". Many people come to SO and expect the community to spoon-feed them answers, without much effort on their own part. We see this time and time again.

With SO heavily promoting Jobs, I suspect applicants are expecting to be spoon-fed their jobs as well. I have no evidence of this. Only second-hand information and hearsay (more on this later).

### The Search Begins

About a year ago, I began looking for a new job. The first thing I did was work with a professional writer to update my resume. One of the best $300 I've ever spent. Next, I updated my SO Jobs profile and then set my status to actively looking along with the specific tech stack and locations I was interested.

Within a week I was contacted by several companies ranging from Amazon to small shops. With each prospective employer contacting me, I did my due diligence and either declined to interview with them or accepted the invitation to interview. In either case, I made my decision within 24 hours.

### Dream Job?

One company in particular caught my attention; they had everything I was looking for in the next stage of my professional life. Without too many details, the company was a small established company in Europe looking for someone to lead their entire development team and assume the responsibilities of their tech stack. After several interviews and providing a solution to one of their real-world issues, I was invited to a face-to-face meeting with the CEO. I was offered the position. After negotiations, I declined as we could not come to an agreeable compensation package.

To this day I have minor regrets as I would have landed my dream job in my dream country. However, the reality of compensation was a driving force and is something we all must realistically address.

### The Search is Suspended

I had already withdrawn my application everywhere else as I knew the European job was what I wanted. Anything less than that was just going to be a let-down. So, I decided to take a personal-reset and resume the job search once my current job had wrapped up its major release.

### The Search Resumes

Fast forward to these past few months where I ramped up my job search. Once again, I turned to SO Jobs. This time I inverted the process and actively looked-for companies I wanted to work with based on their tech stack, location, and other publicly available information.

Within a month, I had narrowed my search down to four companies and began the application process. One simply did not respond. Another outright rejected me. The other two invited me to an interview. Of the two companies that invited me, they were my top two choices and were the best match for my skillset and desired working conditions.

### Offers are Received

After going through both interview processes (multiple interviews and coding exercises), I was offered a position at each company. The offers were generous, well exceeding a base salary of $125k, a signing-bonus, plus yearly bonuses, plus equity, and the usual benefits. After additional negotiation and weighing the pros and cons of each offer and company culture, I made my decision.

### Is the Developer Talent Pool Shallow?

I had some candid conversations with both companies about their experience finding developers on SO. The common thread was most of the developers they found through SO were below average and many were outright horrendous. Given 10 applicants, maybe one or two would make the cut for the initial interview after submitting a rather basic coding exercise.

And let's be honest with each other; any developer worth their salt can get a job anywhere. It's not that difficult. The questions will always be: Is this a job I actually want? Does it provide me a compensation package that meets my needs? Will I be provided the opportunities to further my career? Am I good fit in the company culture?

## Specific Answers to O.P.

#### What were their challenges?

When a company openly posts an ad with a $100k+ base salary, there are going to an inordinate number of applicants flooding in from SO. For smaller companies, this influx of applicants can be difficult to manage. Once I understood this, my approach was slight modified to actively follow up and pursue the company rather than play the waiting game. In every case, it paid off.

#### How soon did they land an interview?

Typically, mutual contact with a company would take upwards of one week; sometimes two. However, after contact had been made, the first interview was almost always within a week. The interview process was always fairly standard with 3-4 rounds of interviewing and a couple of code exercises.
A very rough time-line (all are approximate):

- Two weeks to prepare my resume and update my SO Jobs profile.
- One month (four weeks) searching for companies on SO Jobs.
- One to two weeks to initiate mutual contact with a company.
- Three weeks of interviewing and negotiation before a final offer was received.
- Total: 2 + 4 + 2 + 3 = 11 weeks

#### Was it any different from other sites?

From my perspective, SO Jobs specifically targets developers. For the most part, companies advertising on SO Jobs are going to be more developer friendly than a standard IT shop. In other words, corporate IT shops where dev is a cost-center are a dime a dozen. Boutique shops focused around their development teams are difficult to find; SO Jobs is one of the few places to find these types of companies.

## TL;DR

Finding the right job is a difficult task. Your story will only be as successful as the amount of time and effort you are willing to invest.

#### Let me put it another way

> The purpose of SO Jobs is to be the match-maker. The rest is up to
> you.

Comment: The issue with SO is the false measure of reputation. It leads employers to believe that high SO "reputation" implies that the applicant is reputable. My experience with high rep SO users is in agreement with the employers you interviewed - "horrendous". Given the stakes, it may actually be a technically fraudulent measure.

Comment: Both parties need to perform their due diligence; candidates need to research the company; companies need to research the candidate on SO. With every question and answer posted, the employer should have a good idea of the candidate's skill set and communication. Reputation is only one-factor out of several. "Horrendous" is really reserved for some of the worst candidates; most were simply below average.

Comment: Unfortunately "due diligence" also now includes results from "social networks" like SO (a label which SO mysteriously rejects, given reputation is a social measure). Again my point being that SO "reputation" is a false measure of any stature, social or otherwise. Your other points should be obvious to all.

Comment: @534F I am a marketing manager at Stack Overflow.  I'd love to talk with you about your experience.  Please contact me at  bturriff@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing special about SO Jobs vs say glassdoor except that its current concentration is on programming.  I believe the folks who are hiring don't know how to use the tool properly or the team has not built enough functionality on it to give it any meaning.  To me it is a black hole.  You send your resume in and you don't hear back from anyone.

You are left in an empty state where you end up never knowing why or how or when or whatever happened to this job.  It's a deal breaker for me...I have not had any success getting people and no success finding a job on SO Jobs.  I have had much more luck using indeed.com and other job sites.  I don't think the interface (as I've used it in both ways) that is presented to employers is suitable or easy to use.  Yes you can post a job but that is about all you can do.

Other things that hinder this process is they do not allow us programmers to review companies or rate jobs that are posted.  They make their money on said employers and feel it would discourage employers from posting should they receive negative feedback.  Slippery slope if you ask me.

Comment: *"To me it is a black hole. You send your resume in and you don't hear back from anyone."* I've had exactly the same experience, but always assumed it was just me. I'm not sure if it makes me feel better or worse to see that I am not alone...

Answer (score 5):

I've shared my feedback about jobs [more than once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A189134+jobs). The product has it's flaws that make finding that ideal job a real challenge. However, I was unhappy in my previous job, so SO Jobs was one of the job sites I used to look for full time remote positions.

I worked for a company for over a decade in various divisions. This is a large company and I guarantee that you've seen their products. Unfortunately, they are also very cyclical. When the economy is doing well, I got a nice bonus. When the economy sucked...well, there go 10,000 jobs in less than half a year. I survived those cuts, but it's stressful as the cuts get closer and closer to your "very important project". These types of cuts also cause other tensions to surface - those that aren't let go, while grateful for the job, still resent upper management. New HR policies are implemented and a slow downward spiral starts...until the economy and business recovers and then everyone forgets what just happened because we have large bonuses again. Repeat again in about 6 quarters.

Due to where my spouse works and where I worked, I had about a 100 mile drive daily. This sucked. I was given the "privilege" being able to work from home one day a week.

That provides the motivation I had for looking for a new job. I wanted a full time remote position and I wanted a new environment. Thus, my tentative search began.

---

I started watching Stack Overflow Careers and then Jobs for remote positions that sound interesting. One of the benefits of still having a job is that I could be picky about what I was interested in doing. Slowly, I'd put out an application to a company that looked interesting and would allow me to work remotely full time.

A few things I noticed about this:

- Roughly half of the companies I applied to just use SO as a job board. The application isn't done on SO, you are redirected to their own application portal.
- The companies that do use SO, if they responded to me, responded in less than a few days. The other options was being completely ignored. I am pretty sure that there is only one company that didn't respond in less a week that did eventually send me a rejection notice and that was Stack Exchange themselves. If I didn't hear from someone in a week, I just assumed I'd failed the HR keyword test and counted that application as a rejection.
- I had several interviews from companies I found on SO Jobs. The results of these interviews varied greatly

  - One company drastically changed the job description between the time they set up the interview and the time the interview actually occurred, two days later. This was a major technology company that everyone reading this post has heard of (and likely used their service). Needless to say, I decided that wasn't the position for me.
  - One company advertised a job as a Python position but performed the technical interview using JavaScript. I don't really know JavaScript. That was off putting. This was also a major technology company that many here have heard of.
  - One company had me go through the usual interviews, provided a verbal offer and then two days later told me they didn't have the budget for the new team I'd have been leading. Dodged that bullet. 4 months later they asked if I was still interested in the position. I said no.
- No one ever asked me about my reputation or my moderation positions on the Stack Exchange network (I wasn't an SO mod before finding my current job)

The technical challenges that I mentioned above are related to being able to find those jobs that are interesting. I set up a handful of quick searches that I used and would quickly look for new listings. This was [problematic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350962/do-not-create-recent-searches-for-intermediate-search-steps-in-jobs) because that wasn't intended as a quick search. It was intended as [recent history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350962/do-not-create-recent-searches-for-intermediate-search-steps-in-jobs). I also found that ["remote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316527/can-the-jobs-careers-team-explain-to-employers-the-purpose-of-the-remote-optio) to some companies doesn't mean "full time remote", it means "every once in a while you can work from home...but we'll look down on you for doing so".

My biggest complaint, though, and the reason I started doing just the four most recent searches instead of browsing my suggested "matches", was due to these [matches not being ordered by date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312540/on-jobs-how-do-i-sort-by-most-recent-matches). It was explained in the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312543/189134) to that question that post date is considered in the sorting, but not a big priority. This meant that on the matches page I'd have to scan the entire page for something new, to see if it was buried between postings that were weeks old. This is incredibly frustrating. The recent searches solved that problem because I could easily sort by date in those results.

---

Those were the negatives. The positive is that I did find a new company. I was called a day after I put in my application. All of the interviews were performed by highly qualified people that I now work with. The entire process, from application to start date, was about 6 weeks—with three of those being my fault because I was finishing my previous job. I've been in the new position for a little over two months and love the job.

SO Jobs wasn't really the reason I found the job, though. It was listed on several other sites and they all linked back to the SO Jobs posting. I don't remember if I saw it here first or was linked to it from elsewhere.